# Source for Rabbi Jonathan Eybeschutz's explanation of Ta'anis Esther

Tags: passover, fast-days, megillat-esther, acharonim

The three day fast that Esther and Mordecai and the Jew's of Shushan observed during Nissan fell out on (at least) the first day of Passover. I remember hearing an explanation from Rabbi Jonathan Eybeschutz on how could Jews fast on Passover, when it is a mitzva to eat and drink, (matza, four cups of wine, among other things).

Does anyone know the explanation and the source for it?

Comment: For background source material, see *Esther* ([4:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3304.htm#16) in light of [3:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3303.htm#12)); *M'gilla* ([15a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=15&format=text),ויעבור מרדכי אמר רב שהעביר יום ראשון של פסח בתענית); *Esther Rabba* (8:7, וצומו עלי... שלשת ימים אלו הן י"ג וי"ד וט"ו בניסן, שלח לה והרי בהם יום ראשון של פסח...); *Yalkut Shim'oni* (§1056, ענה מרדכי ואמר לאסתר איני יכול לבטל...). The discussion you are looking for is in *Ya'aros D'vash* ([2:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32683&pgnum=308)).

Comment: If anywhere the Yaaros Dvash,I will try to look it up

Comment: @sam It is. See the end of my above comment.

Comment: Does it mention that the Jews ate a kezayis matzah?